# Обособление обстоятельств

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли я поставила запятую после слова "дистанционно"?

Управление арматурой можно осуществлять вручную или дистанционно, с помощью выносного блока управления.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, запятая поставлена верно.

Comment: Спасибо большое.